# How to handle conditional logic in Scala within the map function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I got a small snippet of Scala code that I'd like to optimize to be more functional.

I got the following

```
val foo: Option[Double]
val bar: Map[String, Double]
```

And a method which takes an `Option[Map[String, Double]]`

So in my business logic, I try to determine if `foo` is defined. If it is, I have to pass `None` to the method, since both `foo` and `bar` cannot be simultaneously present.

I currently handle this in the following way

```
val newOptionalMap = if (foo.isDefined) {
      None
    } else {
      Some(bar)
    }
myFunction(newOptionalMap)
```

I'd like to turn this into a more functional approach. I tried with

```
val newOptionalMap = foo.map(_ => bar)
```

But this is failing, since it's never actually defining `bar` as `None`, thus my method fails as it doesn't expect both `foo` and `bar` to be simultaneously defined.

Which functional approach could I take to simplify the conditional logic?

Comment: `foo.fold(Option(bar))(_ => None)`

Comment: The functional way to solve this is to re-model your data so you don't have both fields. Probably an ADT or something which make it clear only one of the two options is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two way to handle your problem.

As stated by @jwvh you can easly used `fold`:

```
val newOptionalMap = foo.fold(Option(bar))(_ => None))
```

Another way could be using pattern matching:

```
val newOptionalMap = foo match {
   case Some(_) => None
   case _ => Some(bar)
}
```

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/449td4/fold_or_pattern_matching_with_an_option/) there is a discussion about fold or pattern matching usage,